# Error invoking bsh method: eval Could not initialize class

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to jmeter, and I'm getting this error:

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Could not initialize class stpl.lib.enc.tea.TEALib

I have added the jar file of the java class in the lib/ext of the jmeter. I'm trying to import the java class in the beanshell preprocessor. The package name is `stpl.lib.enc.tea` and the class name is TEALib so used the syntax:

```
import stpl.lib.enc.tea.TEALib;

TEALib t = new TEALib();    

String x = "ABCD";

vars.put("p2",x);
```

Also I have added a dll file in the java class which is also named as TEALib. So sometimes I also get the error saying no TEALib found in class.library.path.

The jmeter throws the two errors above.

Answer (score 0):

1. For .jar file - copy it to JMeter's /lib folder. JMeter restart is required to pick the .jar up
2. For .dll file - make sure it lives under one of the following locations:

   - somewhere in [java.library.path](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/)
   - somewhere under system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

You may add folder where .dll file lives to java.library.path using one of the following approaches:

- add the next line to *system.properties* file (located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

  ```
  java.library.path=/path/to/folder/where/dll/lives
  ```

  Again, JMeter restart is required to apply the property.
- set it via `-D` command line argument as:

  ```
  jmeter -Djava.library.path=/path/to/folder/where/dll/lives/  -t /your/testplan.jmx
  ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.